# Display image instead of text for hyperlink

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

How can I display an image instead of a text for a hyperlink? Please see my example, here you can see the text "x" and the background image. I want to show only the background image for the hyperlink.

http://jsfiddle.net/8rfyT/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.cancel {
    background: url(http://www.softicons.com/download/web-icons/light-grey-square-icons-by-axialis-team/png/16/Cancel.png) center no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

make the link `display: block;` so you can give it the width and height of the background image, then use `text-indent` to hide the actual text

#### [Your fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/8rfyT/8/)

Comment: thanks. can u tell what `text-indent: -9999px;` does exactly?

Comment: @sunjie it indents the text (the "actual X") - normally this is used to give text a positive ident like a hanging paragraph, but in this case it does it negatively, a huge amount, so the text is actually way off the left of the page

Comment: Hiding text content with text-indent is bad for SEO. Although it depends on what your doing [See article](http://www.thatwebguyblog.com/post/demystifying_googles_text_indent_mystery)

Answer (score 0):

Add a span and hide it's content.

```
<a href="" class="cancel" title="Cancel"><span>X</span></a>

.cancel span {display:none}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the x in your link (and replace it by a white-space)

```
<a href="" class="cancel" title="Cancel">&nbsp;</a>
```

Change your css to:

```
.cancel{
    width:58px; /* width of image */
    height:58px; /* height of image */
    display:block; /* block so always the whole image will be shown */
background:url(http://www.softicons.com/download/web-icons/light-grey-square-icons-by-axialis-team/png/16/Cancel.png) center no-repeat;


}
```

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8rfyT/5/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting text between the `<a> </a>` tags, put an `<img>`

```
<a href="" class="cancel" title="Cancel">
<img src="http://www.softicons.com/download/web-icons/light-grey-square-icons-by-axialis-team/png/16/Cancel.png" />
</a>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<p>Create a link of an image:
<a href="#">
<img src="smiley.gif" width="32" height="32" />
</a>
```

see this simple example http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_imglink

Comment: -1 for W3Schools reference. It's not a good source of information. Follow the [campaign](http://www.w3fools.com)

Comment: I found it to be a very good place for beginners and I learned most of my basic web programming skills from there

Comment: @sandeep you are repeating what raynos said and btw the information I gave is correct and accurate

Comment: iam not checked raynos link but we are saying same thing.